# ExtJS panels enable on expand

Tags: extjs, panels

I have 5 panels created in ExtJS 4.0. Initially 1st one is enabled and expanded and second one is enabled but collapsed, what I want to do is to enable the other one's as the user expands the previous panel. Let's say panel 3 is disabled, and whenever user expands panel 2, panel 3 enables (but stays collapsed) and when panel 3 is expanded, panel 4 becomes enabled and so on.

Comment: Have you tried initializing the next panel in the callback? If the ID is panel_1, you could know to then initialize panel_2, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you should just be able to attach event listeners on `expand` to do what you want.  You might bubble the event in order to make a single listener.

Something like:

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    defaults: {
        bubbleEvents: ['expand']
    }, 
    items: [
        item1,
        item2,
        item3
    ],
    listeners: {
        scope: this,
        exand: function(panel) {
            var nextPanel = findTheNextPanel(panel);
            nextPanel.enable();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that solved it! Thanks alot SeanA. I have another question. All these panels are in viewport, and when I open it in IE the viewport has a scrollbar but the panels(that are long) go down the page and the scrollbar doesnt scroll that much to show it completely, what's the way to fix this?

Comment: Hmmm, I'd have to see some code in order to diagnose.  Make sure you are using a `layout` in all your components (typically `fit` layout if you only have one item), and you may need to set `autoScroll: true` if an individual panel needs to scroll past its configured height.

Comment: I have 3 <div>s floated like this

[panel 1] [panel 2] [panel 3]

and I have 3 panels, rendered in corresponding div's

so each of the 3 panels have 2 panels inside it I didn't declare a layout in it, I know there is a way to do this without using CSS to float (most likely using table layout)

Comment: Don't fight the Ext layout manager.  Instead of floating your divs manually, use a `Ext.Container` with a certain `layout` to do what you want (a Ext.Container is just a DIV in the dom).  Browse the layout manager here: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/layout-browser/layout-browser.html